# Can you tell if a document has had its metadata altered?

Tags: microsoft-word, metadata, forensics

I'm dealing with a situation in which the other party has fabricated logs. These logs are presumably in docx or doc formats.

A large part of the issue is that the logs are not contemporaneous - they were created much later than that. I know that viewing the metadata of the document would reveal this. I also know that metadata is alterable.

Is it possible to ascertain if a file has had its metadata altered, specificall, a microsoft word doc, and is so, how hard would it be do to do so and are there ways around it?

Comment: why on earth would you accept logs in word format? it is more or less certain that this is not the native log format, so someone was responsible for making that format change, meaning that even the original files origins are suspect regardless of whether the file was subsequently modified.  ask yourself why are you getting logs from this entity (auditing, forensic analysis, investigation, etc), and thus what are the best practices for requesting, receiving, and storing log files persuant to that usecase.

Comment: I know of no way to verify that something has not been altered.

Comment: @FrankThomas Sorry I should have been more clear. I meant logs as in date/time + description of events e.g. "On 8th nov, events A,b,c occurred". So someone essentially opening a doc and creating a fake timeline/ evidence of events.

Comment: @yepitsmeyourlookingfor Edit that into your question please

Answer (score 2):

I do not think I have ever seen logs in Word format, but it is technically possible.  However, receiving log files in Word format is *extremely* unusual.  Based on that alone, its impossible to say if the logs were exported in that format or were cut and pasted.

In order to verify the authenticity of a log file, you would need access to the device that created the logs.  You would probably need to enable auditing on the files system as well.  Unless you have control of the device making the logs, nothing will be 100% certain.

Comment: sorry, I should have mentioned that by log files, I didn't mean system generated logs. I meant things like dates with descriptions of events occurring ( i know ,that seems odd)